# map_int() to vectorize user defined function

Tags: r

I defined the following function, that counts the number of weekdays in a period.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
fx_weekdays <- function(start_date, end_date){
  start_date <- as_date(start_date)
  end_date <- as_date(end_date)
  sum(!weekdays(seq(start_date, end_date, "days")) %in% c("Friday", "Saturday"))
}
```

Next I would like to loop over the following data frame using map_int(), and add a new column, to capture the results.

```
df <- data.frame(start_date=c('2018-1-1','2018-2-1'),
           end_date=c('2018-1-31','2018-2-28'))

df %>% 
  mutate(n_weekday = map_int(df, fx_weekdays(start_date, end_date)))
```

I get an error.

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: 'from' must
>   be of length 1.

I don't know what i am missing, since the follwing expamle works as expected.

```
fx_weekdays('2018-3-12', '2018-4-12')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `map2_int` instead?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df %>% mutate(n_weekday = map2_int(start_date, end_date, fx_weekdays))
#>   start_date  end_date n_weekday
#> 1   2018-1-1 2018-1-31        23
#> 2   2018-2-1 2018-2-28        20
```

Comment: What is the difference between map_int and map2_int ?

Comment: @ronencozen, the `map2` functions allow you to supply two arguments to iterate over in parallel when supplied to a function (instead of just one argument for `map`). In this case, we needed to supply both `start_date` and `end_date` to `fx_weekdays()`. For comparison, perhaps take a look at the `map` examples at https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html vs some `map2` examples at https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you need `map_int`, you can however do it with `rowwise`

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(n_weekday = fx_weekdays(start_date, end_date))

#  start_date end_date  n_weekday
#  <fct>      <fct>         <int>
#1 2018-1-1   2018-1-31        23
#2 2018-2-1   2018-2-28        20
```

---

and I am sure you must be aware you can do this with base R `mapply` as well.

```
df$n_weekday <- mapply(fx_weekdays, df$start_date, df$end_date)

df
#  start_date  end_date n_weekday
#1   2018-1-1 2018-1-31        23
#2   2018-2-1 2018-2-28        20
```

Comment: Intresting approach, Thanks!